# Titanium - Map custom annotation rotation

Tags: android, dictionary, titanium, appcelerator, markers

I'm trying to display the wind on a map. For each pin on my map, I'd like to change color and orientation in order to represent the force and the heading of the wind.

Here's what I've done :

```
var pinWindLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({ width:Ti.UI.SIZE, height:Ti.UI.SIZE, text:'\ue958', font:{fontFamily:Ti.App.ICONS, fontSize:25}, touchEnabled:false });
var pinWind = Ti.UI.createView({width:Ti.UI.SIZE, height:Ti.UI.SIZE});
pinWind.add(pinWindLabel);
```

And, in the API response :

```
for(var k=0; k<res.length; k++){

    if(res[k].wind_avg < 10){
        pinWindLabel.setColor('green');
    } else{
        pinWindLabel.setColor('blue');
    }

    var pin = Map.createAnnotation({
        latitude: res[k].lat,
        longitude: res[k].lng,
        image:pinWind.toImage(),
    });
    annotations.push(pin);
}
```

I had difficulties to change the color of each pin. Without the 'toImage()', I think it's not possible. But now, it works :)

Now I'd like to change its orientation. But even with this code, the pin has always the same orientation :

```
var pinWindLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({ width:Ti.UI.SIZE, height:Ti.UI.SIZE, text:'\ue958', font:{fontFamily:Ti.App.ICONS, fontSize:25}, touchEnabled:false });
var pinWind = Ti.UI.createView({width:Ti.UI.SIZE, height:Ti.UI.SIZE});
pinWind.transform = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix({rotate: 236});
pinWind.add(pinWindLabel);
```

So, how can I do to, first of all, rotate all pins, and, after, rotate each pin in the for loop ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Instead of rotating pins, how about using such images **[Tilted Pin - click here](http://www.stickpng.com/img/icons-logos-emojis/pins/shiny-red-map-pin)** in which pins are already rotated?

Comment: Yes, It's a solution, but I have to make an image for lots of wind orientations, that's why I was wondering if it was possible with a rotation ... but I'm probably going to do that :)

Comment: Though I have never tried to apply matrix animations on annotations because I don't want to face unexpected bugs when my app is in public. But using pre-defined images (who cares if you even puts 50 images) will definitely make your work much easier without any bugs/issues. So go ahead & do some hard work :) .. it will make your app stable & faster since you will directly be using only pre-defined images.

Comment: I made every image as you advised me, my map now works perfectly :)
Thanks !

Comment: Great, let me add it as an answer & you can mark it as accepted to help other users know the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As advised in comments section, in this case, it's more efficient to use pre-rotated image files ***[Click here to see Rotated Pins](http://www.stickpng.com/img/icons-logos-emojis/pins/shiny-red-map-pin)*** as pins.

Though you will need to create many images, but it's most efficient solution across all platforms without much code & complexity.

Another point to note is that modifying images at run-time takes more computation power, so it's always recommended to apply least modifications especially on images at run-time. Always have optimal-resolution & least-size images for faster loading.